# Finding Expectation and Variance of a Subset

Tags: probability, random-variables

You have a box containing $20$ LEGO bricks, $4$ of which are broken. You randomly take $3$ bricks out of the box. Let $X$ be the number of broken LEGO out of the $3$ bricks.

Find $\mathbb E[X],\ Var (X)$, and $Var (20 − X)$.

My method so far to find the expectation is to find each probability (of zero broken, one broken, two, three). I struggle to find the probability of one or two being broken, I'm just not sure how to find these.

For variance, I will use the formula of $\mathbb E(X^2) - \mathbb E^2(X)$, but I'm not sure how to compute the expectation of $X^2$? 0^2 is $0$ and 1^1 2, but 2^2 is 4 and 3^2 9 so would the expectation of these not be 0?

Comment: Use the combinations to calculate probability. For the squares, the idea here is that you calculate probabilities for $x$, yea, like you would normally do, but then, when you calculate expectation, you use the squared version of x in the formula but the probabilities remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to do the calculations manually, first observe that your rv can take values in

$$\{0;1;2;3\}$$

with probability, respectively:

$$\left\{\frac{\binom{16}{3}}{\binom{20}{3}}; \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{16}{2}}{\binom{20}{3}} ;\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{16}{1}}{\binom{20}{3}} ;\frac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{20}{3}}\right\}$$

and so calculate $E(X)=\Sigma_i x_ip(x_i)=3/5$ and $V(X)=E(X^2)-E^2(X)=204/475$

Obviously $V(20-X)=V(X)$

If you do not want to do all the calculations observe that you rv is an [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) thus mean and variance are known values

Comment: thank you, I got it

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

Number the $3$ bricks with $i=1,2,3$.

Then let $X_i=1$ if brick $i$ appears to be broken and $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Then $X=X_1+X_2+X_3$ and with linearity of expectation and symmetry we find:$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb EX_1+\mathbb EX_2+\mathbb EX_3=3\mathbb EX_1=3P(X_1=1)$$

So it only remains to find the probability that the first brick is broken (I leave that to you).

Variance can be found by exploiting the bilinearity of covariance:$$\mathsf{Var}X=\mathsf{Covar}(X,X)=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3\mathsf{Covar}(X_i,X_j)=3\mathsf{Var}X_1+6\mathsf{Covar}(X_1,X_2)$$

So here it only remains to find the variance of $X_1$ and the covariance of $X_1,X_2$.